# Wrong array detail in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want get my product conditions as array in order to add them in cart, this is `dd` of my product when I try to add it in my cart:

```
array:6 [▼
  "id" => 4
  "name" => "product four"
  "price" => null
  "quantity" => "1"
  "attributes" => array:1 [▼
    "attr" => array:2 [▼
      "name" => "weight"
      "value" => "45"
    ]
  ]
  "conditions" => array:2 [▼
    0 => CartCondition {#685 ▼ // need to add this
      -args: array:4 [▼
        "name" => "Black"
        "value" => "10000"
        "type" => "additional"
        "target" => "item"
      ]
      -parsedRawValue: null
    }
    1 => CartCondition {#692 ▼ // need to add this
      -args: array:4 [▼
        "name" => "12 inch"
        "value" => "25000"
        "type" => "additional"
        "target" => "item"
      ]
      -parsedRawValue: null
    }
  ]
]
```

> As you see unlike my `attributes` my `conditions` not show just as
>   array but get values in `-args:` and `-parsedRawValue: null`

When I try to add product in cart I get this error:

```
Darryldecode \ Cart \ Exceptions \ InvalidItemException
validation.required
```

[Error](https://ibb.co/mZy3RS)

This is my function (how I get my `conditions` and where i use them:

```
public function addingItem(Request $request, $id)
{
      //finding product
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      //get product weight
      $weight = $product->weight;
      //list of discounts
      $discounts = Discount::all();
      //get current time
      $mytime = Carbon::now();

      // get product weight in cart as attribute
      $weightArray = [
        'attr' => [
              'name' => 'weight',
              'value' => $weight,
        ]
      ];


      $customAttributes = [];  // my conditions comes from here
      if(!empty($request->attr)){
          foreach($request->attr as $sub) {
          // find the suboption
              $sub = Suboption::find($sub);
              if (!empty($sub->id)) {
                  $itemCondition1 = new \Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array(
                      'name' => $sub->title,
                      'value' => $sub->price,
                      'type' => 'additional',
                      'target' => 'item',
                  ));

                  array_push($customAttributes, $itemCondition1);
              }
          }
      }

      //adding product, options and conditions to cart
      Cart::add(array(
        'id' => $product->id,
        'name' => $product->title,
        'price' => $request->input('harga'),
        'quantity' => $request->input('quantity'),
        'attributes' => $weightArray,
        'conditions' => $customAttributes,  // added here
      ));
      Session::flash('success', 'This product added to your cart successfully.');
      return redirect()->back();
}
```

any idea why i get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: you are adding CartCondition object. Do you want to add array or CartCondition Object?

Comment: @usrNotFound yes it must be as array in case have more than 1.

Comment: @usrNotFound my package documents sample code `// or add multiple conditions as array
Cart::condition([$condition1, $condition2]);`

Comment: Yeah i get that you have your pre-requisite but should you not just add array then CartCondition object if you want it to be array?

Comment: @usrNotFound `should you not just add array then CartCondition object` in which part? PS: `(if i didn't misunderstood your point)` the whole if statement things around my condition is because 2 reasons: 1- some products may not have any condition to user choose 2- user may not choose any condition for his order to add.

Comment: change this `$itemCondition1 = new\Darryldecode\Cart\CartCondition(array('name' => $sub->title, 'value' => $sub->price,'type' => 'additional'))` to just add array `itemCondition1 =
 ['name' => $sub->title, 'value' => $sub->price,'type' => 'additional']` and what is `CartCondition`?

Comment: `CartCondition` if facade of my package have no idea why but in all samples they used it. here is is https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart/#conditions

Comment: @usrNotFound even with `[]` and removing `CartCondition` I get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165384/discussion-between-usrnotfound-and-mafortis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SOLVED

validation issue was caused by empty price value and that was because my loop in front end while getting diffirent price on discounts time and other times, by fixing my price loop i have my product price all the time and it not return null in my function anymore.

thanks for helps.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to convert a collection to array just use [->toarray()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-toarray)
Also it is a bad practice to run a query inside a foreach loop because of N + 1 query problem you may want to consider using of findMany() rather than find()
also you may want to read about [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) too

Comment: Sure `toArray()` would convert collection to array but can you see he's actually converting array into CartCondition object.

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand is this the answer?

Comment: I agree with this.  Running logic on the collection rather than the array will be much more effective.